# Passing cancellation token from Angular to MVC app to multiple APIs

Tags: c#, .net, angular, webapi

I have an Angular application running on top of the .NET MVC application (.NET Framework 4.8) which sends the http requests to the API (also .NET Framework 4.8) and from there, the requests are sent to other APIs. I want to be able to pass the cancellation token to all those APIs, when the request is cancelled in the browser.
In Angular I'm using switchMap operator but I also tried simple unsubscribe and in both cases it works the same way - cancellation token is correct in the MVC app, but it doesn't seem to be passed to the APIs. Here is my code (simplified):
Angular

```
private request$ = new Subject();
private response$ = this.request$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.apiService.getData()));

// in other part of the code, I'm subscribing response$ and triggering the next request 
// when needed (sometimes previous request is not completed yet). 
// This successfully cancels request in browser.

this.request$.next()
```

MVC

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<SomeClass> Get(string url, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new System.Uri(url)
        };

        // this part works fine i.e. IsCancellationRequested is set 
        // to true when request is cancelled
        if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, ct);
        // ...
        // more code here
        // ...
        }
     }
}
```

API

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData()
{
     CancellationToken cancellationToken = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.CallCancelled;
     if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
          // get data, make request to another API, process and return data
     }
}
```

I have also tried following in the API

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
          // get data, make request to another API, process and return data
     }
}
```

But the cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested is always false in APIs (unless the 45s timeout happens). Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I think it is impossible. Your browser side cancellation token is not associated with the server side in any way, so browser side cancellation has no impact on the server side. The server side cancellation token is mapped to `HttpContext.RequestAborted` which only fires under some conditions, https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: Will HttpContext.RequestAborted be set when the request is cancelled in the browser and then in MVC? How to get that property in web API when using .NET Framework 4.8 (that article is about .NET Core)?